# SimCity clone performance

Tags: python, performance, game, pygame

I am working on a *SimCity* clone, and I am noticing a drop in frame rate as I add more objects to my map, now this is expected, but, when I fill the whole screen, the game maintains about 300 FPS.

Will it hold this as I add a lot more objects, or will it continue to drop?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import choice

#inits
pygame.init()
font=pygame.font.Font(None, 18)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption('City Game | Pre-Alpha')
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

#sprites
curspr=pygame.image.load('curs.png').convert()
curspr.set_alpha(100)
grassspr=pygame.image.load('grass.png').convert()
roadspr=pygame.image.load('road.png').convert()
forestspr=pygame.image.load('forest.png').convert()
water1=pygame.image.load('water1.png').convert()
water2=pygame.image.load('water2.png').convert()
res=pygame.image.load('res.png').convert()
house1_0=pygame.image.load('house1_0.png').convert()
house1_1=pygame.image.load('house1_1.png').convert()
res.set_alpha(215)

#vars and lists
tilelist=[grassspr,roadspr,forestspr,water1,res]
namelist=['Grass','Road','Forest','Water','Residental']
tiles=[]
sel=0
money=10000
moneydraw=font.render('Funds: '+str(money), 1, (255,255,255))
namedraw=font.render(namelist[sel],1,(255,255,255))
mse=(0,0)
waterframe=2000
pop=0

class Tile(object):
    def __init__(self,pos,spr,typ):
        self.typ=typ
        self.spr=spr
        self.pos=pos
        self.rect=pygame.rect.Rect(pos[0],pos[1],32,32)
        self.adv=0

while True:
    pygame.display.set_caption(str(clock.get_fps()))
    namedraw=font.render(namelist[sel],1,(255,255,255))
    screen.fill((2,110,200))
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==QUIT:
            exit()
        if e.type==MOUSEMOTION:
            mse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[K_LSHIFT] or key[K_RSHIFT]:
                if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(1,0,0):
                    tilesatmouse=[t for t in tiles if t.rect.collidepoint(mse)]
                    if not tilesatmouse:
                        if sel==4:
                            tiles.append(Tile(((mse[0]/32)*32,(mse[1]/32)*32),tilelist[sel],'res'))
                        else:
                            tiles.append(Tile(((mse[0]/32)*32,(mse[1]/32)*32),tilelist[sel],'tile'))
                elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(0,0,1):
                    for t in tiles:
                        if t.rect.collidepoint(mse):
                            tiles.remove(t)       
        if e.type==KEYUP:
            if e.key==K_e:
                sel+=1
                if sel==len(tilelist):
                    sel=0
            if e.key==K_q:
                sel-=1
                if sel==-1:
                    sel=len(tilelist)-1

        if e.type==MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if e.button==1:
                tilesatmouse=[t for t in tiles if t.rect.collidepoint(mse)]
                if not tilesatmouse:
                    if sel==4:
                        tiles.append(Tile(((mse[0]/32)*32,(mse[1]/32)*32),tilelist[sel],'res'))
                    else:
                        tiles.append(Tile(((mse[0]/32)*32,(mse[1]/32)*32),tilelist[sel],'tile'))

            if e.button==3:
                for t in tiles:
                    if t.rect.collidepoint(mse):
                        tiles.remove(t)

    for t in tiles:
        if t.spr==water1 or t.spr==water2:
            if waterframe>999:
                t.spr=water1
            else:
                t.spr=water2
        if t.typ=='res':
            if t.adv>=0:
                t.adv+=1
                if t.adv==2000:
                    t.spr=house1_0
                if t.adv==4000:
                    t.spr=house1_1
                    pop+=choice([1,2,3,4])
                    t.adv=-1
        screen.blit(t.spr,t.pos)
    waterframe-=1
    if waterframe==0:
        waterframe=2000
    clock.tick(999)
    screen.blit(curspr, ((mse[0]/32)*32,(mse[1]/32)*32))
    screen.blit(moneydraw, (2,2))
    screen.blit(namedraw, (2,18))
    pygame.display.flip()
#if any(t.rect.colliderect(x.rect) for x in tiles if x is not t):
```

Comment: You ask: `Will it hold this as I add a lot more objects? Or will it continue to drop?` ... well, have you tried that and observed what happens?

Comment: Watch out for complicated expressions inside loops. Whereas in C it's useful to decrease strength of operation, in Python it's often worth decreasing the number of operations. As it happens, none of the instances of this are in tight loops, but you could reduce both by turning `((mse[x]/32)*32)` into `(mse[x] & 0x7fffffe0)`.

Comment: @rolfl, I haven't tried, there is only so much room on the screen. But when I get around to adding scrolling, I will test this. @Michael Urman, What is `&0xfffffe0`??

Comment: @SamTubb - `xxx/32` is the same as `xxx >>> 5` (and `xxx/2` is `xxx >>> 1` ...), and `xxx*32` is the same as `xxx << 5`. The effect of `(xxx>>>5)<<5` is to 'blank' out the five least significant bits in `xxx`, which is what `xxx & 0xffffffe0` does!

Comment: Clear as mud now?

Comment: I've never even heard of this? You sure it works with python?

Comment: @rolfl Never mind! I implemented it and it worked like a charm! Thanks! Now, what does this do again?

Comment: 32 is the 5th power of 2. Any multiplication or division by a power of 2 can be expressed as a bit-shift. In decimal, the same is true for 10. E.g. `12345 / 1000` is 12345 shifted right 3 times (1000 is the 3rd power of 10), which (in integer terms truncates the decimal) is `12`. So, `(12345/1000)*1000` is 12000. Which is the same as just setting the units/tens/hundreds digits to `0`. Michael, in binary instead of decimal, has just pointed out that a binary number divided then multiplied by 32 is the same as setting the low-5 bits to 0, and that is what the `& 0xffffffe0` does

Comment: The title of your post should only contain the function/purpose of your code; questions are meant for the body.

Answer (score 11):

As you asked in your question, I'm going to *try* and address your performance issues here. Some of this will be a style review though, so bear with me.

---

## Style

- First off, no offense, but this code looks, not so great. You have many major style issues, so here's a list of some of the major ones I see.

  - You have no spaces between operators. You should have space between all operators. For example, if I wanted to assign `x` to `1`, it should look like this, `x = 1`, and not this. `x=1`
  - Your variable naming is just horrendous. For example, you named a variable `sel`. I have no idea what this variable does, or what it's purpose is. Good variable names should not be too short, or too long, and should reflect clearly on that variable's purpose.
  - This code needs to be separated into various different functions/classes. Right now there's some top-level variables, one class, and a `while` loop doing most of the work. Try and see if there are ways to separate this into separate functions, e.g, a function for checking key actions, or another for rendering the tiles.

  You can find these and many other recommendations in [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/),
  the Python coding style guide.

---

## Performance

- First off, from what I can see, you're doing a lot of looping through the list storing the tile data. This is where your problem is. The more you loop through the data, and the larger the data gets, the slower your program will run.
- If you have any loops that are looping through the data and checking for an item with a specific value, it's better to use `if..in` instead.
- As mentioned in the comments, you can also shorten some of your expressions. For example, the following expression, `((mse[x]/32)*32)`, can be shortened into `(mse[x] & 0x7fffffe0)`. While shortening expressions is something that isn't easy to do, (even I can't do it very well), see where you can do things like this.

---

Anyways, I hope that this review helped! If you want me to add on anything else, just ask about it in the comments, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Dude coming back to look at my stack overflow 8 years later, now working full time as a software developer. Just had to let you know that 14-year-old-me really retained all of those tips you gave me about code styling. Thanks man haha

Comment: @SamTubb Even though, after many years, I'm not doing software any more (full-time auto technician now), I'm glad that I was able to be of help. :)

Answer (score 8):

You have several `if` conditions that cannot be true at the same time:

> ```
> if e.type==MOUSEMOTION:
>     # ...
>
> if e.type==KEYUP:
>     # ...
>
> if e.type==MOUSEBUTTONUP:
>     # ...
> ```

Such conditions should be chained with `elif` in between.
Otherwise, even after we already know that `e.type == MOUSEMOTION`,
the other conditions will be evaluated too, needlessly.

---

You do this kind of thing at so many places,
it would be better to put it into a function:

> ```
> (x / 32) * 32
> ```

Perhaps something like this:

```
def drop_lowest_5_bits(x):
    return x & 0x7fffffe0
```

As you notice, the name of the function documents what this does.

---

You could benefit from some more imports,
so that you can reduce all that code prefixed by `pygame.`.
For example I would import these names:

```
from pygame.image import load
from pygame.rect import Rect
from pygame import mouse
from pygame import key
```